# Django: Get Model of DetailView in init()

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

Hello I'm trying to access the Detail Views model in it's own **init**() method. I've got the following code so far:

**views.py**

```
class AccountDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Account
    template_name = 'account_detail.html'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AccountDetailView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        timeline = kwargs.get('timeline')
        history = History.objects.filter(timeline=timeline).first()
        payHistory = history.topay_set.filter(payed=True, internal_source=self.object).order_by('-payDate')
        paginator = Paginator(payHistory, 10)
```

The Problem is the "self.object" in the payHistory. 
How can I access the Account from the DetailView?

I get the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Janik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Janik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Janik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Janik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 62, in view
    self = cls(**initkwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Janik\Documents\GitHub\jConomy\jConomy\apps\Account\views.py", line 45, in __init__
    payHistory = history.topay_set.filter(payed=True, internal_source=self.object).order_by('-payDate')
AttributeError: 'AccountDetailView' object has no attribute 'object'
```

Comment: *"The Problem is the "self.object" in the payHistory"*... **What is the problem?**

Comment: This bit doesn't work. I want this this bit to be the Account of the Detail View.

Comment: show the error traceback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `self.object` is set on `get` method, not `__init__` method.

I think you can use `self.get_object()` instead.

#### Edit

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    timeline = kwargs.get('timeline')
    history = History.objects.filter(timeline=timeline).first()
    payHistory = history.topay_set.filter(payed=True, internal_source=self.object).order_by('-payDate')
    paginator = Paginator(payHistory, 10)
    context['paginator'] = paginator
    return context
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'AccountDetailView' object has no attribute 'kwargs'

Comment: Yes, I see; Why you are doing this in the `__init__` method? are you trying to pass the `paginator` to the template?

Comment: Yes that's my goal.

Comment: @JanikSpies Check edit. You don't need to do that logic in the `__init__`. Simply move the logic to the `get_context_data` so that you have access to the `self.object` and other attributes as well.

Comment: Ah ok got it. Thank you very much!